# Predicted array has a strange shape

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, tfidfvectorizer

The dataset contains 3 columns: comment, parent_comment and label (0 or 1). I try to predict label for y_test, but have an error

```
Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 758079]
```

Somehow the shape of y_predict is (2,0). 
Why is that and how to fix it?

When I do

```
y_test = y_test_["comment"]
```

everything is fine.

For some reason y_predict has a shape (2,) while y_truehas a normal shape (252694,)

[image]

```
x_train, y_test_ = train_test_split(df1, random_state=17)
y_test = y_test_[["comment", "parent_comment"]]
y_true = y_test_["label"]

tf_idf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = 'english', ngram_range=(1, 2), max_features=700000, min_df=0.01)
# multinomial logistic regression a.k.a softmax classifier
logit = LogisticRegression(C=1, n_jobs=4, solver='lbfgs', 
                           random_state=17, verbose=1)
# sklearn's pipeline
tfidf_logit_pipeline = Pipeline([('tf_idf', tf_idf), 
                                 ('logit', logit)])

tfidf_logit_pipeline.fit(x_train[['comment',"parent_comment"]], x_train["label"])
y_predict = tfidf_logit_pipeline.predict(y_test)

accuracy_score(y_predict, y_true)
```

Comment: To which line your error occures?

Comment: @PV8 last one, where I try to measure accuracy

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your train/test-split which is not posted here. If you check this: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20199/train-test-split-error-found-input-variables-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-sam you need to have the same length of X and y for splitting.

A check-up for this is:

```
X.shape 
Y.shape
```

Followed the post to remove the error:
o fix this error:

1. Remove the extra list from inside of `np.array()` when defining X or remove the extra dimension afterwards with the following command: `X = X.reshape(X.shape[1:])` .
2. Transpose X by running `X = X.transpose()` to get equal number of samples in X and Y.

**Update:**
With your last comment:
Check shape of `y_predict, y_true` this is probably not matching

Comment: But I need to train on 2columns, not one

Comment: probably the shape of `y_predict`and `y_true`ar enot matching if the error occurce in the last line

Comment: This is exactly what I'm talking about. y_predict is array([0, 0], dtype=int64)  (shape (2,)) and y_true has a shape (252694,) and I don't know why

Comment: then check shape `y_true`

Comment: I checked and wrote it in my pevious comment. y_true shape is (252694,),like it should be